# 192.168.1.24 is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 503

Tags: magento-1.7

I deleted 2 unnecessary attributes from Manage Attributes in backend. When I saw in frontend, it is showing  **192.168.1.24 is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 503**

I tried seeing error_log file as well as index.php but found no error.

It was working fine before deleting attributes.

[image]

Comment: if backend is working fine, than recreate those 2 attributes.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento yes, now its working fine

Comment: Have you flushed your Magento cache? If these attributes have been removed but still exist in cache then Magento could be trying to load something that doesn't exist. If possible also check your apache error log, fatal PHP errors will prevent Magento from writing anything to system.log or exception.log, but should still be written to apache error log.

Comment: @VincentHornikx yes, I have re-indexed and also flushed cache., ok, I will check apache error log file.

Comment: @VincentHornikx I have checked in var/report/  folder in that I found the error i.e a:5:{i:0;s:79:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'offers' in 'field list'";i:1;s:4775:"#0 .   Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said the problem appears after you deleted those attributes, simple way to fix is `Recreate those attributes`.... next time make sure you do any changes to localhost/demo/staging site than only you must do in Live site....